# Is there a way to set up a parameterized dashboard for TFS (in addition to the team dashboard)?

Tags: tfs, dashboard

I would like to be able to setup a TFS Dashboard that dynamically updates based on a parameter (e.g. Customer) that I set on the Dashboard itself.  I have a set of TFS Queries that I would like to link into the Dashboard that all use the parameter - and I'd like to pass the parameter from the Dashboard to the Queries.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

The dashboard doesn't support parameters, it can only be configured with the basic work item queries.